# Can W.G. Sebald's walks in "The Rings of Saturn" be traced?

Tags: setting, german-language

In W.G. Sebald's 1995 novel *The Rings of Saturn*, the author describes different walks he takes. In some paragraphs, he describes the paths he takes very carefully, while in others he only mentions directions or how long he walked.

Can those walks be traced in the real world or is Sebald too vague?

Comment: There appear to be a  [research and a video by The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/video/2011/jan/25/sebald-suffolk-walk-documentary-video) which attempted to do this, but I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how accurate this is, as I haven't read the book, but I found an online map which seems to map the exact paths he took, so it seems that you *can* take the same journey as him.

The website is called LITMAP (Literature Maps) which appear to have used google maps to trace the paths. It can be found [here](http://barbarahui.net/litmap/).

I'll add a couple of screenshots below:

It starts off and has the majority of sites around the east of England:

[image: Map showing tracks centred on East Anglia]

But zooming out reveals it is across the world:

[image: Map showing world tracks]

It also very helpfully has text down the side for each location with the relevant quote from the book. It also has page numbers. It starts at the Norfolk and Norwich Hospital University and ends at Coburg, which reading the summary of the book suggests this map is accurate.

Also note that by clicking on a section of text in the right hand column, it highlights that particular place in the map.